# Splitting plot pane for different plotting shemes in R

Tags: r, plot, r-sp

I have a technical question therefore I am not producing a code here.I have two plots. One was created using  base R and the other one was created with sp package. I want to see those packages splitted into two in a row to make comparisons.
So what should I do? All the functions that I know so far  like "par" and "layout" are for designing plotting pane in base R.
Should I convert one plot into base R too? or vice versa
Note: Both plots are maps one is a thematic map like using color fill of a variable in a map. The other one is also a map using a color scheme for quantitative breaks.

Comment: The `cowplot` package allows you to combine plots produced by different frameworks. Maybe it'll work for you. See this vignette: https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/mixing_plot_frameworks.html

Comment: Thank you @Vincent1  I aldready know that someone has already been  faced with this problem and alraeady came up with a solution.

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you. @Vincent